# Chatbot user flow, booking design

Tags: artificial-intelligence, chatbot

we are recently implementing a chatbot solution for my mother's culinary class business. A valuable use case is making appointments through the bot. Seeing how she's got a lot of available times across 7days of the week, it's pretty unpractical to list out all the slots for the user. So we thought of filtering the selections by weekday/weekend and AM/PM. But this ultimately tempers the user experience by introducing two more stages before knowing when exactly is available, and also doesn't do much as almost everybody wants to book for the weekends.

Are there more user friendly ways to do this? Our bot is currently guided flow based, meaning most of the interactions are done by the user clicking buttons given by the bot.

Thanks a lot! Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

One small improvement would be not to list options that are already full. So if weekends are already reserved do not offer them, same with AM/PM.

Another improvement would be to create some kind of chat sessions or user database which could track user preferences. So if user scheduled for lets say Monday afternoon in the past, that could be the first option for bot to offer him on next visit.

Answer (score 0):

Just make the chatbot ask the user when he wish to book, then check the availability for time and date. That is the most user-friendly, and what we are used to if we call for book. From that time it should be simpler to offer possible  alternative bookings. E.g first available weekend and weekday.

And, yes, use user profiles for rate them according to business policy.